# Washington Post covers sound design in film:

Tags: film, sound-design, film-sound-design

There's a nice piece by Ann Hornaday with a video in today's Washington Post [here](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2010/10/21/AR2010102107408.html?sid=ST2010102203520).

Comment: Great article! One of the few.

Comment: Wow!!! Amazing article, nice job! Thanks for sharing